# How to load and store word from/to address that index is in a register, MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

How to load and store word from address that index is in a register? in Assembly MIPS
Example:

```
lw $t0, $a0($t1)  and sw $t0,$a0($t1)
```

Those intructions is just for what I will do (incorrect)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this instead of your only `lw` statement:

```
add $a0 $a0 $t1
lw $t0 0($a0)
sub $a0 $a0 $t1
```

The last sub is needed only if you want to restore `$a0` back to the original value.

You can do the same thing for the `sw` part.

Comment: tanks!!!!, i have another probleme that $ao is integer that increment +1, so added sll $a0 ,$a0,2 after to multiply this integer by 4 and now it's work

Answer (score 1):

Microchip microcontrollers contain DSP-extensions with instructions:

```
LBUX rd, index(base)  # load byte
LHX rd, index(base)   # load half-word
LWX rd, index(base)   # load word
```

Where "index" and "base" is GPR registers.

But I did not find the same instructions for storing.

Comment: An equivalent store would have 3 register inputs, vs. a load only having 2 inputs (and one register output).  That might be why Microchip added load versions but not stores.  Mainstream MIPS [didn't like that lack of orthogonality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879095/using-a-register-as-an-offset#comment80708536_46880563), even though some arrays are read-only.  Later mainstream MIPS has indexed loads/stores for *FP* registers, not GPRs.