# Am I allowed to use two registers in a MIPS addressing mode, as an index?

Tags: assembly, mips, instruction-set, addressing-mode

I have the following C row code:

`B[x] = A[x+7] + A[x+2];`

Assuming that **A** is stored in **$s0**, **B** in **$s1** and **x** in **$t0**.

I have got the following MIPS code:

```
add $t1, $t0, 7  
add $t2, $t0, 2   
lw  $t3, $t1($s0)  
lw  $t4, $t2($s0)  
add $t3, $t3, $t4 
sw  $t3, $t0($s1)
```

Now my question is, am I allow to use in MIPS code like this: **$t0($s1)**, if not can anybody explain why and what are the other alternatives I can use?

I searched online and I could not get a proper answer to this issue!

Comment: No you can't. The reason is that they created the ISA like this :) The alternative is to do the addition yourself.

Comment: [Using a register as an offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46879095) has a nice answer why the ISA is designed that way.  The other two duplicates I linked have some examples of how to do the address math yourself using `addu` and a left-shift.